# How to configure the GCS Spark connector to work with two different GCS buckets from two different projects?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth, google-cloud-dataproc

I am looking for a way to configure multiple GCS buckets (from different projects) in the same Spark job. I have been able to solve this a particular way (below) however I suspect there might be a better, more configuration driven, way to do this. I am new to Spark so I am quite sure I am missing something.

I haven't been able to find any references to this in any of the documentation that I searched. All documentation talks about config for connecting to a single bucket or multiple buckets in the same project accessible with the same credentials. Primarily, the issue boils down to being able to provide different credentials for the different buckets to access.

So I have -

```
GCP Project 1
GCS bucket1 and some resource path1
this is accessible via serviceAccountKey1.json

AND

GCP Project 2
GCS bucket2 and some resource path2
this is accessible via serviceAccountKey2.json

// they don't have to be different projects as long as the credentials required are different
```

The problem appears to be that although there are several configurable authentication mechanisms, ultimately just one configuration - one set of credentials, one environment key (GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS), one key.json file, etc, gets loaded and there seems to be no way to tie it to the bucket.

So if I do the following, I can access one bucket but cannot provide any configuration for the others. I am guessing that I am missing something here and that there should be some way of providing multiple configurations?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Spark GCS Example")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
  .set("fs.gs.auth.type", HadoopCredentialsConfiguration.AuthenticationType.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_KEYFILE.toString())
  .set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable","true")
  .set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", serviceAccountKeyFile1);
...
spark.read().text("gs://bucket1/path1").show();
...
// conf.set("fs...keyfile", serviceAccountKeyFile2) // Expectedly doesn't get set
spark.read().text("gs://bucket2/path2").show(); // this does not work because I need a different key file to access this bucket
```

I have solved this for now (with caveats) and this is how -

#### My current solution

It involves setting an `AccessTokenProvider` class in the following fashion.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("Spark GCS Example")
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .set("spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
  .set("fs.gs.auth.access.token.provider", ReplacableAccessTokenProvider.class.getName())
  .set("fs.gs.auth.type", HadoopCredentialsConfiguration.AuthenticationType.ACCESS_TOKEN_PROVIDER.toString());
```

and priming it before accessing GCS -

```
ReplacableAccessTokenProvider.jsonFilePath = serviceAccountKeyFile1;
spark.read().text("gs://bucket1/path).show();
ReplacableAccessTokenProvider.jsonFilePath = serviceAccountKeyFile2;
spark.read().text("gs://bucket2/path).show();
```

(*rough, hacky code as POC - not the final solution*)

Since every instance of the load of a `gs://` url via `spark.read().text("gs://bucket1/path")` results in credentials getting loaded, my `AccessTokenProvider` is called and I change the key.json file it uses for that invocation. This is not ideal at all. Also I am not sure if this works in a cluster without stomping on its own toes (experts view on whether this holds up in Spark's parallelism is very welcome). If I could provide some identifier that allowed me to load a map in advance, I would be much more comfortable with this approach. I am hoping there is a better solution via configuration.

My environment is local mode Spark in Java while I try to solve this problem. I am hoping for an Apache Spark solution (not one for Dataproc).

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is supported by GCS connector, but it could become a feature request. The most common way is to use just one SA with permissions on all buckets the job needs to read or write.

Comment: Thanks. I too ended up with the same suspicion looking into the code but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a Spark way of doing this that I was missing. Also, I am looking for any feedback on the approach using the AccessTokenProvider in a Spark cluster environment. One SA is a valid solution but in our case starts to create friction when it goes across projects.